# VS Code Prettier - How to disable auto new lines in function arguments?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm using [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) v6.4.0 and I found it annoying when it automatically add new lines to my function arguments.

For example, this is the format that I desire:

```js
const Header1 = styled.h1`
  ${maxWidth(500, () => css`
    font-size: 36px;
  `)}
`;
```

However, Prettier would add new lines to the function arguments when it formats the code:

```js
const Header1 = styled.h1`
  ${maxWidth(
    500,
    () => css`
      font-size: 36px;
    `
  )}
`;
```

How can I configure Prettier to stop the above behavior? I do not want to add `// prettier-ignore` inside the tagged template literal though, since this format pattern would be very common in my codebase.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Prettier docs? https://prettier.io/docs/en/index.html

Comment: Yup I've taken a look at the [configuration options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) but I'm not sure which configuration will suppress that behavior

Comment: same here, anyone has an answer for this instead of pointing at the doc ? hopefully not everyone answers that way